# Why would my AWS MySQL snapshot data be older than a manual backup I did 12 hours earlier?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds, snapshot

I'll try to keep this as succinct as possible.

I was asked by my boss to make a duplicate of one of our apps with an empty DB but the same schema/structure for a venture he is doing with another company.

So like any good developer, I backed everything up on the server and made a snapshot of the DB in the RDS dashboard. This was at approx 10 pm.

Then I spun up a new ec2 and MySQL instance for the new venture and got everything networked and running there.

That's when everything went wrong.

Somehow my production DB for our app appeared to be a mirror of the new one that I made for the other company and it had no data. (Im still looking into how this happened but suspect that MySQL Workbench is to blame)

At this time I am feeling fine and dandy and just go grab the snapshot I made a few minutes earlier and restore it.

Low and behold the data is old and outdated. Now I'm freaking out but I knew that I had a manual backup I had done earlier in the day before running some pretty large insert scripts (10 am) so I just ran an import from that and the data seemed to be correct for the time that I backed it up, 10am that day.

So not all was lost. Only a day worth of updates and inserts but that is a lot of money for the company.

To get to the main question, How is it remotely even possible that a snapshot taken at 10 pm has older data than a manual backup done 12 hours earlier?

Comment: It should not *be* possible.  My next course of action would be to create more new instances from these snapshots and examine them again.  The fact that something also happened to your production DB suggests that something important is being overlooked, but it's effectively impossible to speculate what. (I would suggest the process of deploying the new service may have damaged your production DB due to hard-coded hostname and credentials.) If you run into future issues, don't stop any instances or delete anything.  Not sure how this question can be answered, here.

Comment: ...unless of course you are using MyISAM tables, in which case, just about anything could go wrong.  Are you?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The hardcoded creds has to be it! That makes total sense. Tks man.

Comment: And no not using MyISAM :)